# Modular HTML JS button not closing menu when another selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a modular split button via html and plain js. I have managed to get the menus to shut when I click out of the menu, if a menu item is selected or the button is clicked again. However, when I select another menu button with the other menu already open both menus will stay open.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is a code fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/leightonv/65mzLg3p/2/

Below is the code:

```js
let count = 0;
let button = '';
let menuContent = '';

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

  if (button !== document.activeElement) {
    count = 0;
    button.parentElement.querySelector('.menu-content').classList.remove('open');
  }
})

function onClick(event) {
  button = event.currentTarget;
  menuContent = button.querySelector('.menu-content')

  if (button === document.activeElement) {
    button.parentElement.querySelector('.menu-content').classList.add('open');
    count += 1
    if (count >= 2) {
      button.parentElement.querySelector('.menu-content').classList.remove('open');
      count = 0;
    }
  } else {
    // button is auto focused :)
    // TOGGLE ON ICON

  }
  console.log(count)
}
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 4px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu-content.open {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-content .link {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.menu-content .link:hover {
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
}

.dropdownArrow {
  padding: 0 4px 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dropdown-menu menu-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn-style" onclick="onClick(event) ">
        Print<i class='dropdownArrow fa fa-caret-down'></i>
    </button>
    <div class="menu-content">
      <input type="button" class="link" value="Print Selected" onclick="console.log('boo')" />
      <input type="button" class="link" value="Print belected" onclick="console.log('bee')" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu menu-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn-style" onclick="onClick(event) ">
        Print<i class='dropdownArrow fa fa-caret-down'></i>
    </button>
    <div class="menu-content">
      <input type="button" class="link" value="Print Selected" onclick="console.log('boo')" />
      <input type="button" class="link" value="Print belected" onclick="console.log('bee')" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't complete the way you start but I think this what you want.

**A simple Click away or click outside**

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button.btn-style');

const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-content');

let pop = true;

btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  pop = false;

  const pre = document.querySelector('.menu-content.open');
  const curr = event.currentTarget.closest('.dropdown-menu').querySelector('.menu-content');

  if (pre !== curr)  pre?.classList.toggle('open');
  
  curr.classList.toggle('open');

}))

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (pop) menus.forEach(menu => menu.classList.remove('open'));
  pop = true;
})
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 4px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu-content.open {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-content .link {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.menu-content .link:hover {
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
}

.dropdownArrow {
  padding: 0 4px 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu menu-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn-style">
    Print<i class='dropdownArrow fa fa-caret-down'></i>
  </button>
  <div class="menu-content">
    <input type="button" class="link" value="Print Selected" onclick="console.log('boo')" />
    <input type="button" class="link" value="Print belected" onclick="console.log('bee')" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu menu-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn-style">
    Print<i class='dropdownArrow fa fa-caret-down'></i>
  </button>
  <div class="menu-content">
    <input type="button" class="link" value="Print Selected" onclick="console.log('boo')" />
    <input type="button" class="link" value="Print belected" onclick="console.log('bee')" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you make the javascript so complex. You can simply do it like this:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.btn-style");
const menus = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-content");

buttons.forEach((i, n) => {
  i.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menus.forEach((j, x) => {
      if (n !== x) j.classList.remove("open");
      else menus[n].classList.toggle("open");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 4px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu-content.open {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-content .link {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.menu-content .link:hover {
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
}

.dropdownArrow {
  padding: 0 4px 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="dropdown-menu menu-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn-style">
        Print<i class='dropdownArrow fa fa-caret-down'></i>
    </button>
    <div class="menu-content">
      <input type="button" class="link" value="Print Selected" onclick="console.log('boo')" />
      <input type="button" class="link" value="Print belected" onclick="console.log('bee')" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu menu-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn-style">
        Print<i class='dropdownArrow fa fa-caret-down'></i>
    </button>
    <div class="menu-content">
      <input type="button" class="link" value="Print Selected" onclick="console.log('boo')" />
      <input type="button" class="link" value="Print belected" onclick="console.log('bee')" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```